# Display time in ms in perl

Tags: perl

I want to display time till milliseconds. My code is giving error. Any other method is also welcome.

```
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday/;
use Time::Format qw/%time/;

$s1=gettimeofday;
print qq|$time{'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.mmm', $s1}\n|;
```

Error:

```
syntax error at (eval 2) line 31, near "->import qw(langinfo)"
        ...propagated at C:/Perl64/lib/Time/Format.pm line 77, <DATA> chunk 1.
```

Answer (score 5):

Update your Time::Format. The version you are using is buggy. The bug in question was fixed seven years ago. (in 1.07, on March 31st, 2008).

Or use the following:

```
use POSIX       qw( strftime );
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday );

my ($secs, $microsecs) = gettimeofday();
strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($secs)) . sprintf(".%03d", $microsecs/1000)
```

Comment: Hi, your code prints nothing. Also, how to update my module. I am using ppm install time::format and it says no missing package.

Comment: Re "your code prints nothing", Right. You can tell by the lack of `print`. The repo you are accessing appears to only have the old version you already have. (Odd, since it won't even compile on your version of Perl.) You could use `cpan Time::Format`.